# How do I find the gcloud Kubernetes api url for gitlab integration

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, gcloud, gitlab-ci

I'm using the hosted version of gitlab and gitlab-ci and following the kubernetes integration setup https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/integrations/kubernetes.html.

I'm struggling to find what to enter as the Kubernetes API URL for my gcloud hosted kubernetes instance. I assume I'm missing something obvious :-(

Answer (score 25):

```
kubectl cluster-info
```

or

```
cat ~/.kube/config | grep server
```

Comment: @Camil which one should we write in GitLab?

Comment: @Danpe the in this line: `Kubernetes master is running at https://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx`

Comment: From the GitLab [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/clusters/): `kubectl cluster-info | grep 'Kubernetes master' | awk '/http/ {print $NF}'`.

Comment: What if the master is running at something like https;//172.0.0.3 ?